# Android: Can Custom Keyboard record user's typed text?

Tags: java, android

I want to record a user's typed text in the Android application.
So, I'll make a custom keyboard and record it. 
Can I do that by custom keyboard?

Comment: Yes, that's why they warn you of it when you choose a keyboard.  Of course doing that without warning the user, especially if its uploaded to a server, is considered malware and is at a minimum grounds to be banned from the playstore and in some locales is illegal.